# How to reach items in array on for loop to setting textview

Tags: android, arrays, for-loop

I want to reach consecutive numbers to using an array in for loop. My purpose is; Setting them to my text view. All values taking from one string with split method. Now; It has 6 values. Every 3 parts are one value. I want to reach them like first, forth. How can I do it?

All values set here to array.

```
int count_stack = menu_items_string.length() -  menu_items_string.replace("|", "").length();

    int item_sayısı_integer = count_stack/3;

    String menus[] =   menu_items_string.split(Pattern.quote("|"));
    for (int i = 0; i <count_stack + 1; i++) {
        all_quantity.add(menus[i]);

    }
```

I want to set them to  quantity_textview three by three.

```
    String   items = "";
    for (String ss: all_quantity
            ) {
         items +=  "-" + ss + "\n";


        quantity_textview.setText(items +"\n" );


    }
```

Comment: can you give an example of the array you have, please what you want in the textview?

Comment: Orders from restaurants. It has  3 parts. First quantity, second orders, third fee. I write only one textview to bottom with 3 parts. Example: 1, Happy Meal, 9.65.  This  is  my splitter -----> "|" .  Every category split according to "|".

Comment: you need to use a model.... ill give you an example in a second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this in Eclipse.... but you should get the idea.

```
public class ModelExample {

    int quanity;
    String order;
    double fee;

    public ModelExample(int quanity, String order, double fee) {
        this.quanity = quanity;
        this.order = order;
        this.fee = fee;
    }


    public int getQuanity() {
        return quanity;
    }

    public void setQuanity(int quanity) {
        this.quanity = quanity;
    }

    public String getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public void setOrder(String order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    public double getFee() {
        return fee;
    }

    public void setFee(double fee) {
        this.fee = fee;
    }







public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      List<ModelExample> model = new ArrayList<ModelExample>();
      model.add(new ModelExample(1, "happy meal", 3.99));
      model.add(new ModelExample(5, "burger", 0.99));
      model.add(new ModelExample(8, "shake", 2.99));

      System.out.println(model.size());

      for (int i = 0; i < model.size(); i++) {
          System.out.println("Qty: " + model.get(i).getQuanity() + " Item: " + model.get(i).getOrder() + " Fee: " + model.get(i).getFee());
      }

}
```

This will print out...

```
3
Qty: 1 Item: happy meal Fee: 3.99
Qty: 5 Item: burger Fee: 0.99
Qty: 8 Item: shake Fee: 2.99
```

Comment: First of all ; I am lated sorry. And thanks your answer. It  is definitely true.